# How to Fix Blank Cloudflare Plugin Settings page

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, cloudflare

I recently purchased Cloudflare APO, and during configuration, I installed the Cloudflare Plugin. However, on activation, the plugin’s settings page is blank.
When I checked Chrome Console, I found the errors on the attached

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YQ518.jpg)

I do not know how to resolve this issue as my WordPress website is running on a self-managed Google Cloud Platform.
Could this problem be a result of file path permission?

Please help me to resolve this challenge.

All the fixes I've seen did not work for me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [HTTP 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_server_errors) is a generic server-side error message. On its own it doesn't tell us anything useful. Any time you see this your first step should be to check your error logs for more detail.